# direct sum of linear bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, invariant-subspace

I have a question on (orthogonal) direct sums of an Operator.

In particular, I was wondering if the direct summands of a linear and bounded operator $T$ on a complex Hilbertspace $H$ are all $T$-reducible closed subspaces, where a subspace $M$ is reducible if $T(M)\subset M$ and $T(M^\perp)\subset M^\perp$. Is that true, and if so, why?

I don't know much about direct sums of operators, and the statement I proposed is what I was able to derive from here: [Formal definition of direct sum of operators.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360058/formal-definition-of-direct-sum-of-operators)

thanks in advance

Comment: It is only a matter of choice in the *definition* of what you call "*direct summands* of a linear and bounded operator on a complex *Hilbert space*".

Comment: How would you define it? I read it in a paper and was quite confused about it. If I choose to say that the "direct summands of $T$" are precisely the $T$-reducible subspaces everything that follows in the paper worked out quite fine. So I kind of searched a suitable definition of "direct summand" which is equivalent to what I need, namely being $T$-reducible.

Comment: I believe you were right to choose that definition, i.e. in the context of Hilbert spaces, I think that "direct sum" implicitely means "orthogonal direct sum".